# how to rewrite compressed bitmap to bitmap variable c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, compression

I want to pass compressed bitmap to the Bitmap bmp(variable). This code saves compressed bitmap to the file(compressed) but doesn't change bitmap size which is "in variable", I want to pass it to the variable without creating new file and then reading it. Any ideas? Or maybe I just missed some suitable method?

```
ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 30L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;


        Bitmap bmp = CaptureDesktopWithCursor2();

        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\sebb\Desktop\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        byte[] lol = imageToByteArray(bmp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider to store (or wrap) your data inside a memorystream instead of use a real file ?

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

See that class provided as example

```
public class BitmapWrapper
{
    private MemoryStream _stream = new MemoryStream () ;

    public Bitmap GetBitmap () 
    { 
        return new Bitmap ( _stream ) ; 
    }

    public void SetBitmap ( Bitmap value , ImageFormat format )
    {
        value.Save ( _stream, format ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, works well, not really sure how I missed this :P